# como obtener los valores de un objeto que están dentro de otro objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript

Si tengo el siguiente arreglo en javascript

```
[
  {
    id: {
      a: variable,
      b: variable_2,
      c: variable_3
    } 
  },
  {
    id: {
      a: variable,
      b: variable_2,
      c: variable_3
    } 
  },
  {
    id: {
      a: variable,
      b: variable_2,
      c: variable_3
    },
  }
]
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para obtener solamente los valores de b, en el mismo arreglo original?
Soy nuevo en javascript

Comment: Almacena en una variable a todo ese array de objetos, llamémosle `arr`. Luego haces un `console.log(arr.map(objeto => objeto.id.b));`, saludos.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Agrégalo como respuesta

Comment: @Yussef luego lo hago

Comment: @Cris223511.dev esto funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias!!